# Mismanagement of dask future results slow down the performances

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm looking for any suggestion on how to solve the bottleneck below described.

Within a dask distributed infrastructure I map some futures and gain results whenever they are ready.  Once retrieved I've to invoke a time consuming, blocking "pandas" function and, unfortunately, this function can't be avoided.
The optimum would be to have something that let me create another process, detached from the for loop, that's able to ingest the flow of results. For other constraints, not present in the example, the output can't be serialized and sent to workers and must be processed on the master.

here a small mockup. Just grab the idea and not focus too much on the details of the code.

```
class pxldrl(object):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.table = df

def simulation(list_param):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    val = sum(list_param)/4
    if val < 0.5:
        result = {'param_e': val}
    else:
        result = {'param_f': val}
    return pxldrl(result)

def costly_function(result, output):
    time.sleep(1)
    # blocking pandas function 
    output = output.append(result.table, sort=False, ignore_index=True)

    return output

def main():
    client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=1)

    output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['param_e', 'param_f'])

    input = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(100, 4)),
                                columns=['param_a', 'param_b', 'param_c', 'param_d'])

    for i in range(2):

        futures = client.map(simulation, input.values)

        for future, result in as_completed(futures, with_results=True):
            output = costly_function(result, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run `costly_function` in a separate thread.  Perhaps you could using the `threading` or `concurrent.futures` module to run your entire routine on a separate thread?

If you wanted to get fancy, you could even use Dask again and create a second client that ran within this process:

```
local_client = Client(processes=False)
```

and use that.  (although you'll have to be careful about mixing futures between clients, which won't work)

Comment: To speed up the system the idea would be to process the costly_function in a way that the client.map would be free to go ahead with the second loop. 
I tried, without much success, to implement a second async Streamz process and that's why I'm looking for alternatives. Another attempt I did was to create an async process through the 'aiomultiprocess'. Unfortunately isn't so easy for me to deeply understand how to make all this process asynchronously collaborative.

Comment: how about a sort of cache that is then processed through a Fire and Forget on a local_client as you suggested? that would free the loop to the next one? indeed the cache needed to be passed as a deepcopy otherwise it would be compromised from the next loop.